# Socketswift connection timeout to specific ip address

Tags: python, ios, iphone, swift

I had the idea to connect my wifi wall adapter to my computer. I first watched for other ideas and found that link:[Connecting through pc](http://www.ludwich.de/ludwich/smart_home_IdOTy.html)
In this link is a python code, which I also tried and worked perfectly for me. Than I tried to rebuild it in Swift and found Socketswift. I implemented it and tried to connect to "192.168.2.131" with port 8530, it didn't worked. I'm getting the failure: "connection timeout". Until now I could not figure out what I am doing wrong because when I try the same thing through python it works.
Here is my python code:

```
d = socket.socket()
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM,0)
s.connect(('192.168.2.131', 8530)) # (IP, Port) is a single variable passed to connect function
s.send(bytearray.fromhex('01 40' + mac + on)) # to switch 'on'
time.sleep(5) # sleep for 5 seconds
```

And here my IOS/Swift code:

```
let client = TCPClient(address: "192.168.2.131", port: 8530)

        switch client.connect(timeout: 10){
        case .success:
            print("connected")
            var hex: String = String("01 40" + mac + off)
            var byteArray = [UInt8]()
            byteArray += hex.utf8
            let data: Data = Data(bytes: byteArray)
            let result = client.send(data: data)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
```

Thank you for your answers. I you have any questions or need more information please send me a message

Comment: A search for `TCPClient` in the Apple docs does not give me any matches.

Comment: TCPlient comes from SwiftSocket. I will give you the link to the github: https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket

Comment: Your code will connect with the line: `let client = TCPClient(address: "www.apple.com", port: 80)`, so that means there is something wrong with your IP address or the port.  Maybe the port is already in use?  Or, maybe the server won't accept your attempt to connect at the IP address you used.  I would try changing the port to 12345 first.

Comment: I changed the port to 12345 and now I'm getting the error: unknownError

Comment: Also, it's not clear to me how your python code works--if it does at all.  There are two common protocols: TCP and UDP(SOCK_DGRAM).  TCP employs a connection and a lot of error checking back and forth over the connection to make sure that data that the client sent actually arrives at the server.  If the data doesn't arrive at the server, then the client is told to resend it.  On the other hand, UDP does not use a connection.  Instead, the client just sends data to a port and IP, and if the data never arrives at the server, the server will never know that the data was sent....

Comment: ...Yet, the python code calls `connect()` to establish a connection for a UDP socket, which makes no sense to me.  See [python UDP example](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication) and the [difference between TCP and UPD protocols](https://www.howtogeek.com/190014/htg-explains-what-is-the-difference-between-tcp-and-udp/).

Comment: I guess [calling connect() on a UDP socket](https://erlerobotics.gitbooks.io/erle-robotics-python-gitbook-free/udp_and_tcp/connecting_udp_sockets.html) does do something useful, but it does not establish a connection, so `connect()` will not timeout while trying to establish a connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I use a TCP socket in python, I get a timeout error on the `connect()` call--just like with your iOS code.

Here's a python TCP client you can play with:

```
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  #SOCK_STREAM => TCP, SOCK_DGRAM => UDP
s.settimeout(10)
s.connect(('192.168.2.131', 8530)) 

s.send(bytearray.fromhex('01 40')) # to switch 'on'
time.sleep(20)
```

Results:

```
~/python_programs$ p34 1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 6, in <module>
    s.connect(('192.168.2.131', 8530)) 
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Try using the python TCP code with your setup.  I'm guessing it won't work because the iOS TCP code wouldn't work.  Next, because you said that the python UDP code worked for you, I would try [creating a UDP socket with SwiftSocket](https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket/blob/master/Sources/UDPClient.swift).

Comment: I think it wouldn't work for you because you can't reach this client. I can reach it because the wall adapter has this ip address

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know how I came on the idea that I have to use TCPClient. Now I can send data to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample UDP client and server using SwiftSocket installed with cocoapods:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftSocket

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //This can be a server using localhost on your Macbook as well.
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

            let udpServer = UDPServer(address: "127.0.0.1", port:12033)
            var count = 1

            while true {
                print("Server about to recv() \(count)")
                let(byteArray, sender, port) = udpServer.recv(1024)

                if let byteArray = byteArray,
                   let string = String(data: Data(byteArray), encoding: .utf8)
                {
                    print("Server received: \(string)\nsender: \(sender)\nport: \(port)\n\n")

                }

                count += 1
            }

        }

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

            let udpClient = UDPClient(address: "127.0.0.1", port: 12033)

            switch udpClient.send(string: "Hello") {
            case .success:
                print("Client sent message to server.")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Client failed to send message to server: \(error)")
            }
            udpClient.close()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //This is run on the main queue, after the previous
                //code executes.  Update UI here.
            }
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

--output:--
Server about to recv() 1
Client sent message to server.
Server received: Hello
sender: 127.0.0.1
port: 42998


Server about to recv() 2
```